# Issue with react-animation-components package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-animations

So in my app I am adding react-animation-components by typing

```
yarn add react-animation-components@3.0.0
```

Then I import the **FadeTransform** property

```
import { FadeTransform } from 'react-animation-components';
```

However, I am getting this message stating that the declaration of **react-animation-components** is not recognized.

[image: Message]

I type this

```
yarn add @types/react-animation-components
```

but still nothing.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore this warning. It's typescript's checker complaining it doesn't know about the existence of a module named "react-animation-components". You're using vscode, probably turn on some setting that enables typescript checking to in your project.

You cannot solve it by `yarn add @types/react-animation-components`. I checked, there isn't such a types definition package, no one authors it.

So you either ignore this warning (it's safe), or add your own types definition file to this module. You can do it by creating a `index.d.ts` file at the root of your project and add a one-liner `declare module "react-animation-components"`. Then the typescript checker will leave you alone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I thought that npm package was deprecated.